# 'Most efficient allocation of materials ordered' algorithm :

Tags: algorithm, sorting, frequency

Most efficient allocation of materials ordered java programming question:

Here is a programming question I simply can’t get a handle on. It's an interview question so needs to be solved in 10-15 minutes.

> A company wants to automate the ordering of lumber for three sizes of
>   board into the most cost effective order (longer boards are less
>   expensive).  The lumber available from the lumber company is sold in
>   16’, 12’ and 8’ boards. The longer board, the cheaper.
>
> Orders are made are for multiples units of 7’, 6’ and 5’ boards. So
>   you can get two 7’ boards out of a 16’ one, or three 5’ (out of a
>   16’), etc. If you only had a need for two 5’ boards you would order a
>   single 12’, not a 16’.
>
> Write an algorithm that will take an order for number of mixed boards
>   of the three types and return the most efficient (cost-effective)
>   order in (up to) the three available sizes.

I can’t help but think of the problem with making change in the optimum coinage but that’s relatively simple compared to this one. There seems to be elements of frequency of items but I can’t see how that works with allocation of optimum order.

I see it as a two-step process, the first being where frequencies are tallied up in a Map e.g. 6 x 7 footers, 5 x 6 footers etc. The the frequency map is ordered by value and that's where I get stuck.

Just to clarify: bigger boards are cheaper and should be used first whenever possible.

I'll keep looking at this but if anyone has a thought, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the question, could you give some example of input that would fit in the algorithm, and some example output?

Comment: @EvcanMustafa has a point. Also if you need a 6 and a 7 footer, should you use two 8 footers or one 16 footer? How much cheaper they get is important.

Comment: [Cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)

Comment: In response to David Eisenstat's comment, thank you! Now I know I am dealing with a NP-complete problem (although I have no idea what that means :}) But this does give me a handle. I won't mark it as solved yet until I can see if I can write some kind of algorithm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
package max.test.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * Board Cutter algorithm based on John T Erickson's 
 * code found at http://pastebin.com/1XPiBD20
 * 
 * I can't take credit for it - I just rendered it to Java  
 * 
 * Max Tomlinson
 * 
 */
public class BoardCutter
{

    static List<Double> boards;
    static List<Double> lengthsNeeded;

    static double cutWidth = Double.NaN;
    static double totalBoardLength;

    static int lengthsNeededLeft = 0;

    static List<String> instructions = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> summary = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] tmp = new double[] { 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48 };
        boards = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
        {
            boards.add(tmp[i]);
            totalBoardLength += tmp[i];
        }

        lengthsNeeded = new ArrayList<Double>();

        tmp = new double[] { 36.75, 36.5, 36.5, 26.25, 26.125, 22.5, 21, 20.5,
                14.5, 9.25, 9, 6.5, 4 };

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
        {
            lengthsNeeded.add(tmp[i]);
        }

        cutWidth = 0.125;

        Collections.sort(lengthsNeeded);
        Collections.reverse(lengthsNeeded); //sorted high to low - biggest cuts first

        lengthsNeededLeft = lengthsNeeded.size();

        writeLine("Boards: ");

        double boardSum = 0;

        Iterator<Double> itd = boards.iterator();
        while (itd.hasNext())
        {
            double board = itd.next();
            writeLine("" + board);
            boardSum += board;
        }

        writeLine("Total: " + boardSum);

        writeLine("Lengths Needed:");

        double lengthsNeededSum = 0;

        itd = lengthsNeeded.iterator();

        while (itd.hasNext())
        {
            double ln = itd.next();
            writeLine("" + ln);
            lengthsNeededSum += ln;
        }

        writeLine("Total: " + lengthsNeededSum);

        tryCut();

        Collections.reverse(instructions);

        for (int i = 0; i < instructions.size(); i++)
            writeLine("Cut " + (i + 1) + ": " + instructions.get(i));

        for (int i = 0; i < summary.size(); i++)
            writeLine(summary.get(i));
    }

    /*
     * recursive cutting method
     */
    static boolean tryCut()
    {
        //last case, then exit
        if (lengthsNeededLeft == 0)
        {
            double boardLengthRemaining = 0;

            Iterator<Double> it = boards.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            { // sum
                double board = it.next();
                if (!Double.isNaN(board)) 
                    boardLengthRemaining += board;                  
            }

            summary.add("Boards Remaining: ");

            for (int j = 0; j < boards.size(); j++)
            {
                if (boards.get(j).equals(Double.NaN)) continue;
                summary.add(" Board " + j + ": " + boards.get(j));
            }

            summary.add("Total Remaining " + boardLengthRemaining
                    + " efficiency "
                    + (100 * (1 - (boardLengthRemaining) / totalBoardLength)));

            return true;
        }

        //normal, recursive case

        //loop for all lengths needed
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthsNeeded.size(); i++)
        {
            double lengthNeeded = lengthsNeeded.get(i);

            if (Double.isNaN(lengthNeeded)) continue; //isNaN = 'done'

            for (int j = 0; j < boards.size(); j++)
            {
                double board = boards.get(j);

                if ( Double.isNaN(board)) continue; //isNaN = 'in use'

                double boardRemaining = board - lengthNeeded - cutWidth;

                if (boardRemaining >= 0.0)
                {
                    lengthsNeeded.set(i, Double.NaN); //set this length needed to 'done'
                    lengthsNeededLeft--;

                    boards.set(j, Double.NaN); //set board to used

                    boards.add(0, boardRemaining); //add new cut board remainder to front of available boards for possible reuse

                    int newBoardIndex = boards.size() - 1; //adjust size

                    //recursive call
                    if (tryCut())
                    {
                        instructions.add("Cut board " + (j + 1) + " of length " + board 
                                + " to size: " + lengthNeeded 
                                + " (leaving board " +  (newBoardIndex + 1) + " of length "
                                +  boardRemaining + ")");
                        return true;                        
                    }

                    boards.remove(boards.size() - 1);

                    lengthsNeeded.set(i, lengthNeeded);
                    lengthsNeededLeft++;

                    boards.set(j, board);
                }
            }
        }

        // all boards are too short 

        return false;
    }

    static void writeLine(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
//output
/*
Boards: 
48.0
48.0
48.0
48.0
48.0
48.0
Total: 288.0
Lengths Needed:
36.75
36.5
36.5
26.25
26.125
22.5
21.0
20.5
14.5
9.25
9.0
6.5
4.0
Total: 269.375
Cut 1: Cut board 1 of length 48.0 to size: 36.75 (leaving board 7 of length 11.125)
Cut 2: Cut board 2 of length 48.0 to size: 36.5 (leaving board 8 of length 11.375)
Cut 3: Cut board 3 of length 48.0 to size: 36.5 (leaving board 9 of length 11.375)
Cut 4: Cut board 4 of length 48.0 to size: 26.25 (leaving board 10 of length 21.625)
Cut 5: Cut board 5 of length 48.0 to size: 26.125 (leaving board 11 of length 21.75)
Cut 6: Cut board 6 of length 48.0 to size: 22.5 (leaving board 12 of length 25.375)
Cut 7: Cut board 10 of length 21.625 to size: 21.0 (leaving board 13 of length 0.5)
Cut 8: Cut board 11 of length 21.75 to size: 20.5 (leaving board 14 of length 1.125)
Cut 9: Cut board 12 of length 25.375 to size: 14.5 (leaving board 15 of length 10.75)
Cut 10: Cut board 7 of length 11.125 to size: 9.25 (leaving board 16 of length 1.75)
Cut 11: Cut board 8 of length 11.375 to size: 9.0 (leaving board 17 of length 2.25)
Cut 12: Cut board 9 of length 11.375 to size: 6.5 (leaving board 18 of length 4.75)
Cut 13: Cut board 15 of length 10.75 to size: 4.0 (leaving board 19 of length 6.625)
Boards Remaining: 
 Board 12: 0.5
 Board 13: 1.125
 Board 15: 1.75
 Board 16: 2.25
 Board 17: 4.75
 Board 18: 6.625
Total Remaining 17.0 efficiency 94.09722222222221
*/
```